# Extract data from [__ob__: Observer]

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to get data from a API that i created, this data is listed just as i wanted, but i can't manipulate this data because it returns a [**ob**: Observer]. How can i extract data from this ?

Store.js:

```
    items: state => {
       item.getAll().then(response => {
         state.items = response.data
      })
      return state.items
    },
```

Component.vue:

```
        ...mapGetters(["items"]),
```

```
   <v-card flat v-for="item in items" :key="item.title">
```

Comment: All `getters` need to be synchronous with no side effects. Yours is asynchronous (using `then`) and has side effects (assigning `state.items`). Asynchronous activity in the store should be inside `actions`. The `__ob__: Observer` just means that Vue is observing that array. If the array really does contain the data you think it contains then you'd use it just like any other array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as @skirtle commented i needed to move my function to actions because i'm using a async task.
My final code ended up that way:

```
 getters: {
    items: state => state.items,
  ...
  }

  mutations: {
    'LOAD_ITEMS'(state, data) {
      const items = []
      for (let key in data) {
        const item = data[key];
        item.id = key;
        items.push(item);
      }
      state.items = items;
      ...
    }

  actions: {
    loadItems({ commit, state }) {
      ...
      return axios.get("item.json")
        .then(response => {
          commit("LOAD_ITEMS", response.data);
        }).catch(error => console.log(error));

    }
  }
```

I'm using firebase, so i did a loop to store the key.
 If you has your own API maybe you can just store response.data directly in a JS object without using a loop.